# Error fetching the blocks from another spark node while caching the Rdds

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to fetch the data from `Cassandra 3.9` using [SparkCassandraConnector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector). I have multiple Spark(`1.6`) Jobs which uses the same data. So, I cached it using the following code. [image]

**Spark Code :**

```
  sc.parallelize(partitions, 2*sc.defaultParallelism).map(x => new Partition(x)).joinWithCassandraTable("KEYSPACE","COLUMNFAMILY").on(SomeColumns("partitionkey")).select("partitionkey", "cookie", "query").cache()
```

But few of tasks get failed and throws the following exception :

```
 org.apache.spark.storage.BlockFetchException: Failed to fetch block from 1 locations. Most recent failure cause:
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doGetRemote$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:595)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doGetRemote$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:585)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doGetRemote(BlockManager.scala:585)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemote(BlockManager.scala:570)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.get(BlockManager.scala:630)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection from ubuntu/172.16.0.27:56727 closed
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportResponseHandler.java:124)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportChannelHandler.java:94)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelUnregistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:739)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:659)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        ... 1 more
```

[image]

Where as i don't get any exception while we don't cache the data. Moreover, each node contains the mapping for the `ubuntu` and `ubuntu1` to their respective IPs in their host file.

Also, as mentioned in the screenshot it divided the whole data 8 paritition. SparkCassandra connector should have distributed the jobs intelligentily but why `Locality_Level` it shows is `ANY` Which implies it couldn't find the data on the same node, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved for new version:

> an error which occurs due to failed fetches of NON-shuffle blocks (such as broadcasts or cached RDD blocks).

```
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14209
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17484
```